# Cannot change rydurham/sentinel default page design in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to change default view design provided in [rydurham/sentinel](https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel) and integrate it in my website. I changed the file

> > vendor/packages/rydurham/sentinel/src/views/default.blade.php

But it seems to bring no change.Should i change the view before i publish it? And what does publish mean? As its rendering the view there must be somewhere the code is residing. Where is it? Somewhere in the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For view publish means new view files are created in your view folder according to package specified in

**vendor/packages/rydurham/sentinel/**

For bringing any change you should now bring change to

**app/views/packages/rydurham/sentinel/layouts/default.blade.php**

If you change the views before publishing in vendor folder (where you changed) then it will take effect.